# How to get a column cell value then addition with 1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a gridview:
    A column ( type int ) 
    How can I get a value from a cell of current editing row.
    How to get the value of the cell with the type int then the value + 1 ?

Comment: Show us the GridView's aspx markup. "Editing row" means that you want to handle the `RowEditing` event or the `RowUpdating` event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx

Comment: You haven't shown your aspx part of the GridView. Are you using TemplateFields, BoundFields,AutoGenerateColumns,SqlDataSource,ADO.NET,....?

Comment: I'm using sqldatasource to bind data from table to gridview , option on gridview is set to autogenerateColumns. no I'm not using template fields but I can do it if it's needed

Comment: the edit button is from the gridview not created from 0 , do I need to show you the gridview? It's a simple gridview,with sqldatasource binding the data to it

Comment: It would have helped a lot if you'd posted it at the first place. What does this mean: "How get the value of the cell with the type int then the **value + 1**"? Do you want to add 1 to that value or the int-value of the next cell in that row? Anyway, i assume that my answer should help to do both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the [`RowUpdating`-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx)   which occurs when a row's Update button is clicked, but before the `GridView` control updates the row. When you don't use `TemplateFields` you use the cell's Text property, otherwise use `FindControl` to get a reference to your controls.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow currentRow = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex];
    String intColumnText = currentRow.Cells[5].Text; //assuming it's the first cell
    int value;
    if(int.TryParse(intColumnText, out value))
    {
        //if you want to increment that value and override the old
        currentRow.Cells[5].Text = (value++).ToString();
    } 
}
```

Comment: it's not working it says: argument 2 must be passed with the out keyboard and the best overload method to match for int.TryParse(string,out) has some invalid arguments . And  1.Yes a column is a template field and some are not. 2.Yes I want to add 1 to that value of int.

Comment: I found a way to get the value but how can I add 1 to the value? if the value of the cell is 1 then it will be 2 and so on

Comment: @InaaInzii: I'm not sure if i've understood you correctly. You want to add 1 to the current value? Then simply write `currentRow.Cells[0].Text = (value++).ToString();`. Sorry, i've missed the `out` in `TryParse`(edited).

Comment: yes I want the value from the cell to rise with 1 everytime a cell is edited , this should be in the updating event.

Comment: tried and it didn't worked protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow currentRow = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex];
    String intColumnText = currentRow.Cells[5].Text;
    int value;
    if(int.TryParse(intColumnText, out value))
    {
       (value++).ToString();
    } 
}

Comment: @InaaInzii: Edited my answer since you didn't set the Text.